# .NET Data Adapter Timeout SP Issue

Tags: .net, sql-server, dataadapter

We have a SQL Server stored procedure that runs fine in SQL Manager directly, does a rather large calculation but only takes 50-10 seconds max to run.

However when we call this from the .NET app via a data adapter it times out.  The timeout however happens before the timeout period should, we set it to 60 seconds and it still times out in about 20 seconds or less.

I've Googled the issue and seen others note issues where a SP works fien directly but is slow via a data adpater call.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: If you're setting *a* timeout and it's timing out before that interval then it sounds lieke there's some other timeout you're not setting. Show *us* the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it runs fine in SSMS directly, do you mean that executing the stored procedure itself runs fine, or that the underlying SQL runs fine?

From your description, this sounds like an example of parameter sniffing. Basically, SQL Server has cached an execution plan that is optimal for one set of parameters but exceptionally poor for most others.

You can use the RECOMPILE option on the query in your stored procedure to force recompilation on every execution. If this isn't called frequently or compilation doesn't take long, you can make use of [this trick](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/94369/sql_server_94369.html).

The other solution is to copy the stored procedure parameters into local variables and use those in the query. Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc
  @var1 INT
AS
  DECLARE @_var1 AS INT;
  SET @_var1 = @var1;

  SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM t1
   WHERE t1.pk = @_var1;
```

Comment: In SMSS the SP runs fine every time we try it, by passing it the params jsut as we do via the .NET data adapter.  However if I do force the SP to recompile then it does seem to work for a while on the ,NET side so perhaps it is a plan caching issues perhaps.  Somehow the dataadapter or .NET is getting in the way it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've checked all your timeouts.  I don't know if you're using asp.net or winforms but at least the first two of this list will apply:
[Time out period not elapsed, but still timing out (see code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848628/time-out-period-not-elapsed-but-still-timing-out-see-code/848664#848664)

Another thing to check is that you are setting up your parameters correctly.  Doing it wrong can break indexes.  The place I've seen this is when you have an index on a varchar column that is key to your query, and set up your parameter for that column using a plain "AddWithValue()" or other function that doesn't explicitly set the type.  .Net will give you an *nvarchar* parameter by default because strings in .Net are unicode.  The result is that it won't be able to use the index.

Comment: Winforms app.

Again it owrks fien in SQL but not when called via datadapter.  On top of that is seems very inconsisent, sometimes it might work, other times it times out runnign the same SP from the app and different times.  I'm lost as to why at this point.

Comment: You can tell your .Net code to pull back the execution plan.  That might tell you something. http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/55237/thanks-guysi-got-the-res.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change the timeout property of the SqlConnection object