# Long running query timing out

Tags: sql, asp.net

Have a site running a query which works fine with small sets of data being returned. When the user runs a time frame that takes long to run I keep getting

```
[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] = {"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."}
```

This query does not timeout running on the SQL server itself.

I have the following in the Web.config

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="360000"/>
```

The items run in an update panel so I have this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="360000"/>
```

I have a timeout set in the connection string and set one in the sql command but no change.

Comment: How long does the query take when you run it from management studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if your connection from sql server is configured any different from the connection string you are using. I would suspect that is the reason for it working from the sql server but not the code.
Some options are checked by default in sql server. It should be under tools.
You may add SET statements to your code to match that.

Also see if this would help - http://www.serverintellect.com/support/programming/sql-qtimeout/

Answer (score 0):

This particular error is from the SQL Command You need to increase the timeout on your SqlCommand object. Remember that your UpdatePanel command runs in it's own postback, and so you're working with a different SqlCommand object than one that was used during the full page lifecycle. Make sure you set that timeout somewhere that will be effective for the update panel.

See this answer for more info:

> [Time out period not elapsed, but still timing out (see code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848628/time-out-period-not-elapsed-but-still-timing-out-see-code/848664#848664)

You need to make sure the timeout value at every level of the pipeline is large enough to support this.

Of course, the best option is to tune your query. If you're hitting a 30 second timeout problem, you may want to go back to the drawing board on what you're doing, even to the point of re-thinking the user interface to avoid needing to show too much data.